# Can the word 'impossible' be used postpositively with other than 'mission' nouns?

Tags: grammar

For example, can I say *The teacher gave us the task impossible?*

Answer (score 2):

As an adjective, "impossible" would come before the noun in almost all cases: *impossible task*, *impossible mission*. Most adjectives would be out of place to be used after the noun unless the intent is to add **unusual emphasis** or to sound **archaic** or **poetic** (e.g. *time immemorial*), so "*the task impossible*" would only be acceptable in that context.

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/impossible

So you should stick with "*The teacher gave us an impossible task*" in normal use.

---

More broadly, there are certain circumstances in which the adjective can follow the noun (the postpositive use you mention), but this is only common in normal usage where the phrase is part of a "**set piece**" (e.g. *Princess Royal*, *pound sterling*). These are commonly derived from French or other loan words into English:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postpositive_adjective

http://grammarist.com/grammar/postpositive-adjectives

Other trailing adjectives do exist, as have been raised in the comments, e.g. the use of *proper* as reflexive **emphasis** - "*after the starter, they tucked into the meal proper*". Similarly, they can be used for emphasis in **superlative phrases** such as "*the lowest price possible*". But, again, this is a particular use of particular words and not a generalisation that adjectives can trail the noun in all normal use cases.

And finally, there's the use case in which the postpositive adjective is there simply because **part of the sentence is not**: "*we have a few rooms free*" vs "*we have a few rooms (that are) free*". But you wouldn't extend this to "*we have a few rooms purple*", for example: it is dependent on the specific adjective as to whether such use would be acceptable. This is the general case of the emphatic use, above: "*the lowest price (that is) possible*".

---

**Footnote (and this may be irrelevant):** there's a little confusion in my mind by the mission/impossible combination you led with, so I'll address that separately. If that's in any way related to the film/TV series, then it should always have a colon - "Mission: Impossible", as in "*Here's the mission: but you'll never succeed*" (c/f "*Mission: to go to the shops*", "*Mission: to tickle the cat*", "*Objective: to do* ). It's introducing a mission, and here's the description, which is a simple one word "*forget it, you're doomed*" in this instance.

Comment: You are wrong when you say that adjective *always comes before the noun*, for example *he is a performer extraordinaire*, *we remember times past*. You are also wrong with the colon: just search in google among books, it is used a lot.

Comment: I have to disagree... I understood the OP to be referring to the "Mission: Impossible" TV and film series, in which case there should always be a colon. And the *performer extraordinaire* example simply reflects my final point - French adjectives being after the noun (as in the numerous set pieces/set phrases in English, e.g. God almighty). I'll concede that the adjective may be used postpositively in certain circumstances, but not in the context of the original question. Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postpositive_adjective

Comment: In English, an adjective after the noun signals an object complement.  Only when other factors exclude an OC is the 'French' form acceptable.

Comment: -1 for ' "Impossible" is an adjective, so always comes before the noun'. 'The plane did not land on the runway proper' has a different meaning from 'The plane did not land on the proper runway'. But 'proper' is an adjective in both.

Comment: @ab2 and Edwin - thanks (again) for the constructive feedback for a newcomer. I've liberally edited the answer accordingly, along with further examples. I'll live with whatever downvotes this brings :)

Answer (score 1):

What you are referring to is called a postpositive adjective.  While not common in English, it only takes a few minutes of thought to remember instances of PPA.  This Wikipedia article is very thorough and will help you understand them. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postpositive_adjective.  Seems like you already do, but the article might help you form your own opinion on this or defend the usage if you'd like to use "task impossible" in your writing.

It's a matter of opinion whether task impossible is acceptable or not.  Personally, if I saw it in fiction or non fiction I would be willing to "accept" it, as it is an obvious reference to Mission Impossible.  This of course depends on the tone of the writing and the author's style.  Maybe an article about Hercules: "After finishing his last task impossible, Hercules took a well-deserved rest."  I think a good rule of thumb on new usages is if an average reader can see that someone is referencing a standard usage then it is ok...doesn't always work, but seems reasonable.